# Calling one stored procedure within another stored procedure using variables from first stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure say `@Create_Dummy1` which is being passed a variable. This is declared as `@Dummy_Variable1` in this stored procedure.

Next I need to call another stored procedure  `@Create_Dummy2` from `@Create_Dummy1`. I need to pass `@Dummy_Variable1` in the `exec` statement.

But if I try to do this the string `@Dummy_Variable1` is only being passed instead of the value it holds.

Comment: What does your exec statement look like? Are you using `sp_execute` and passing `exec @Create_Dummy2 @Dummy_Variable1`?

Comment: @Shruti Don't tell us, **show us**. Paste your exact code.

Comment: @Shruti - people edit questions here, to try and make them more readable, follow conventions, etc. Why the rollback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm executing procedures inside other procedures like this:

```
DECLARE @childResult int, @loaErrorCode int, @loaErrorMessage varchar(255) 
EXEC @childResult = [dbo].[proc_sub_getSomething] @schemes_id = @foo_schemes_i, @errorCode = @loaErrorCode OUTPUT , @errorMessage = @loaErrorMessage OUTPUT
```

Should it still not work you should edit your question to show your exact code.

Comment: dbo.Stored_procedure_name Worked.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
create procedure Create_Dummy1
(
    @Dummy_Variable1  int
)
as 

exec Create_Dummy2 @Dummy_Variable1

Go
```

And

```
create procedure Create_Dummy2
(
    @Dummy_Variable1  int
)
as 

Select * From yourTable WHERE tableColumn = @Dummy_Variable1
```

And this is how you call it:

```
exec Create_Dummy1 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work out. This is exactly what i tried. It passed the string [@Dummy_Variable1] instead if value held in this variable. But let me specify that that value stored in this variable [@Dummy_Variable1] is a string